# How to install perlbrew following c compiler error

Tags: c, perl, compiler-errors

I am new to Perl (I am using it for a new specific project), and I am trying to following the following tutorial to install Perlbrew: https://www.ensembl.info/2013/09/09/installing-perl-dbdmysql-and-ensembl-on-osx/

I am running OSX Monterey Version 12.3.

When I run the following code block:

`perlbrew install -j 5 --as 5.14.4 \ --thread --64all -Duseshrplib perl-5.14.4`

I get the following error:

```
Would you like to use it? [y]
clang: error: invalid arch name '-arch try.c'
clang: error: no input files
You need to find a working C compiler.
Either (purchase and) install the C compiler supplied by your OS vendor,
or for a free C compiler try http://gcc.gnu.org/
I cannot continue any further, aborting.
```

I have XCode installed:

```
~ % xcode-select --install                                               
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates
```

How can I direct perlbrew to xcode to fix the working c compiler error?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `invalid arch name '-arch try.c'` looks like a bug in a build file.  I'd suggest filing an issue on Perlbrew's github site.

Comment: Does a modern version of perl build?

Comment: You probably need 5.34 or newer: https://perldoc.perl.org/perl5340delta#Updated-Platforms

Comment: *"invalid arch name '-arch try.c'"* I can reproduce on macOS Ventura 13.1 without using perlbrew explicitly (but after running `/Users/hakonhaegland/perl5/perlbrew/bin/patchperl`). Simply running `Configure` from the source directory like this `sh Configure -de '-Duseshrplib' '-Dusethreads' '-Duse64bitall'` gives the error. Here is the complete log file: https://pastebin.com/v4ypChB9

Comment: Added ticket: https://github.com/Perl/perl5/issues/21512